# Huggingface.js (vanilla JS) - add a custom CSV file

Tags: huggingface

I want to use huggingface.js (vanilla JS) on a page. I have this setup using the CDN and it is working fine with “conversational”. I am using the “facebook/blenderbot-400M-distill” and that is all good.

My question is I want to add in a custom CSV file so that it can get specific information from this CSV file and use it in the chat. e.g how much is X or how long does it take to build.

Is there a way to do this in huggingface.js (vanilla JS) ? if if so how can I do it.

I have read over all the docs and tried a few things but nothing has worked.